# I can not use signin-google to login my .net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I do the same as [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/google-logins?tabs=aspnetcore2x), and I can use google to login with Default debugging, but when I make it in server, it can not work and return 500 error, in the packet ,it loss Location and Cookie,i also make it in docker ,but the same error ,so how can i do for it ?

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
{
    googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
});
```

Comment: i use the same url the same port ,but it just can not work in iis and docker ,it just can work in iis express

Comment: Is there any detail error message? You could follow [ASP.NET Core Module configuration reference][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module], and share us the log in `.\logs\stdout`.

Comment: infoinfo: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler[4]
      Error from RemoteAuthentication: An error occurred while sending the request..
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler[4]
      Error from RemoteAuthentication: An error occurred while sending the request..
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: 操作超时

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?